# Environment based connection string with ASP NET CORE and Docker support

Tags: c#, asp.net, docker, asp.net-core, ef-code-first

I have a ASP.NET Core app with Docker support and following service configuration in the `Startup.cs`:

```
        string connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ORACLE_CONNECTION_STRING");
        services.AddDbContext<BloggingContext>(options => options.UseOracle(connectionString));
```

I set the connection string in the `docker-compose.override.yml`:

```
version: '2'

services:
  continuouseverything:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ORACLE_CONNECTION_STRING=Server=(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL=TCP) (HOST=LOCALHOST) (PORT=1521)) (CONNECT_DATA= (SERVER=DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME=xe.oracle.docker))); direct=true; User Id=system; Password=oracle; Unicode=true
    ports:
      - "80"
```

I works fine when I just start the app via Docker. And in Debugger I can see that the `connectionString` variable got the right connection String.

But when I try to run `Add-Migration InitialCreate` I get an `ArgumentNullException` in the Startup when `services.AddDbContext()` is called because the `connectionString` variable is null.

How do I accomplish this, that the `EnvironmentVariable` is set like defined in the `docker-compose` file?

Comment: How are you running `Add-Migration InitialCreate`?  From Powershell?

Comment: Package Manager Console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running `Add-Migration InitialCreate` directly from Powershell, you need to first set the environment variable in the shell.

`$env:ORACLE_CONNECTION_STRING = "connstring goes here";
Add-Migration InitialCreate`